# Gojs : How do I save data that belongs to the UI and not to the diagram?

Tags: save, gojs

I have a data array updated by the user but it is not part of the diagram.
How do I save it along with the diagram?

Answer (score 0):

You could have that Array be a property on the **Model.modelData** object.  That object is automatically written out by **Model.toJson** and read in again by **Model.fromJson**.  No nodes or links need exist for that information to be saved in the model.  However, the contents of the Array had better be serializable by that method and that static function if you are going to call them.